# How to add scroller around table using html and Javascript?

Tags: html, forms, dynamic, scroll, html-table

I am designed a dynamic table for getting input from user. Each column of table contains different types of fields like text box, drop down, check box etc. What should I do to add a scroller around the table? I searched it on internet but I could only get a solution for plain text in table, and other solutions were much too  complicated. If you can refer me to some site that tells basic about it that will be great.

As below:

```
<table width="98%" border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" align="center">
        <tr>
        <td>
        <input name="addRow" type="button" class="btn" value=" + " onclick="this.form.changeType.value='addRow';document.FileUploadFormatAdd.submit()"></input>
        </td>
        <td>
        <input name="deleteRow" type="button" class="btn" value=" - " onclick="this.form.changeType.value='deleteRow';document.FileUploadFormatAdd.submit()"></input>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

                <td width="3%" class="bandcolorsubheader">Sr No.</td>
                <td width="6%" class="bandcolorsubheader">Field Name*</td>
                <td width="4%" class="bandcolorsubheader">Min Length</td>
                <td width="4%" class="bandcolorsubheader">Max Length</td>
                <td width="6%" class="bandcolorsubheader">Type*</td>
                <td width="4%" class="bandcolorsubheader">Future Date Allowed</td>
                <td width="4%" class="bandcolorsubheader">Past Date Allowed</td>
                <td width="4%" class="bandcolorsubheader">Required Field</td>
                <td width="6%" class="bandcolorsubheader">Depends Upon Field Name</td>
                <td width="7%" class="bandcolorsubheader">Depends Upon Field Value(Comma Separated Values)</td>
                <td width="4%" class="bandcolorsubheader">Min Value</td>
                <td width="4%" class="bandcolorsubheader">Max Value</td>
                <td width="4%" class="bandcolorsubheader">Field Order*</td>
                <td width="35%" class="bandcolorsubheader">Sql Query</td>
                <td width="5%" class="bandcolorsubheader">Date Format</td>
            </tr>
        <input type="hidden" name="noOfRows" value="<%=noOfRows%>">
        <% 
            try
            {
        %>
        <%
        Iterator iterFieldValues=listOfFields.iterator();
        debugger="9";
        %>
        <%
            String classColor = null;
            for (int i=1;i<=noOfRows;i++){
        %>
        <% 
                    if((i%2)==0)
                      classColor = "tblrowwhite";
                 else
                      classColor = "tblrowgrey";
            %>
        <tr>
        <td width="3%" class="<%=classColor%>">
        <%=i%>
        </td>

        <%
        String fieldName=(String)iterFieldValues.next();
        %>
        <td width="6%" class="<%=classColor%>">
        <input type="text" class="ibox" name="<%="reqdFieldName"+i%>" value="<%=(fieldName!=null)?fieldName:""%>" size="20" MAXLENGTH="100"  <%=operationType.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("view")?"readonly":""%>>
        </td>
        <%
        String minLength=(String)iterFieldValues.next();
        %>
        <td width="4%" class="<%=classColor%>">
        <input type="text" class="ibox"  name="<%="minLength"+i%>" value="<%=(minLength!=null)?minLength:""%>" size="10" MAXLENGTH="5" <%=operationType.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("view")?"readonly":""%>>
        </td>
        <%
        String maxLength=(String)iterFieldValues.next();
        %>
        <td width="4%" class="<%=classColor%>">
        <input type="text" class="ibox" name="<%="maxLength"+i%>" value="<%=(maxLength!=null)?maxLength:""%>" size="10" MAXLENGTH="5" <%=operationType.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("view")?"readonly":""%>> 
        </td>
        <%
        String fieldType=(String)iterFieldValues.next();
        %>

        <td width="6%" class="<%=classColor%>">
        <select name="<%="reqdType"+i%>" class="cbox"  onchange='EnableFields(this)' <%=operationType.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("view")?"disabled":""%>> 
        <option value=""  >Select</option>
        <%
            Iterator iter=fieldValidationTypes.iterator();
            while(iter.hasNext())
            {
                String fieldValidationType=(String)iter.next();
                if(fieldValidationType!=null&&!fieldValidationType.trim().equals(""))
                {

        %>

        <option value="<%=fieldValidationType%>" <%=fieldType.equals(fieldValidationType)?"selected":"" %> ><%=fieldValidationType.toUpperCase()%></option>
        <%
                }
            }
        %>
        </select>
        </td>

        <%
        String isFutureDateAllowedValue=(String)iterFieldValues.next();
        %>

        <td width="4%" class="<%=classColor%>">
        <input type="checkBox" value="1"  name="<%="isFutureDateAllowed"+i%>" <%=isFutureDateAllowedValue.equals("1")?"checked":""%> <%=(!operationType.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("view"))&&fieldType.equalsIgnoreCase("Date")?"":"disabled"%> > 
        </td>
        <%
        String isPastDateAllowedValue=(String)iterFieldValues.next();
        %>
        <td width="4%" class="<%=classColor%>">
        <input type="checkBox" value="1" name="<%="isPastDateAllowed"+i%>" <%=isPastDateAllowedValue.equals("1")?"checked":""%> <%=(!operationType.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("view"))&&fieldType.equalsIgnoreCase("Date")?"":"disabled"%> > 
        </td>
        <%
        String isReqdFieldValue=(String)iterFieldValues.next();
        %>

        <td width="4%" class="<%=classColor%>">
        <input type="checkBox" value="1"  name="<%="isReqdField"+i%>" <%=isReqdFieldValue.equals("1")?"checked":""%> <%=operationType.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("view")?"disabled":""%> > 
        </td>
        <%
        String dependsUponFieldName=(String)iterFieldValues.next();
        %>
        <td width="6%" class="<%=classColor%>">
        <input type="text" class="ibox" name="<%="dependsUponFieldName"+i%>" value="<%=(dependsUponFieldName!=null)?dependsUponFieldName:""%>" size="20" MAXLENGTH="100" <%=operationType.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("view")?"readonly":""%>> 
        </td>
        <%
        String dependsUponFieldValue=(String)iterFieldValues.next();
        %>
        <td width="7%" class="<%=classColor%>">
        <input type="text" class="ibox" name="<%="dependsUponFieldValue"+i%>" value="<%=(dependsUponFieldValue!=null)?dependsUponFieldValue:""%>" size="20" MAXLENGTH="500" <%=operationType.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("view")?"readonly":""%>>
        </td>
        <%
        String minValue=(String)iterFieldValues.next();
        %>
        <td width="4%" class="<%=classColor%>">
        <input type="text" class="ibox" name="<%="minValue"+i%>" value="<%=(minValue!=null)?minValue:""%>" size="10" MAXLENGTH="10" <%=operationType.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("view")?"readonly":""%>>
        </td>
        <%
        String maxValue=(String)iterFieldValues.next();
        %>
        <td width="4%" class="<%=classColor%>">
        <input type="text"  name="<%="maxValue"+i%>" class="ibox" value="<%=(maxValue!=null)?maxValue:""%>" size="10" MAXLENGTH="10" <%=operationType.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("view")?"readonly":""%>>
        </td>
        <%
        String fieldOrder=(String)iterFieldValues.next();
        %>
        <td width="4%" class="<%=classColor%>">
        <input type="text"  name="<%="reqdFieldOrder"+i%>" class="ibox" value="<%=(fieldOrder!=null)?fieldOrder:""%>" size="10" MAXLENGTH="3" <%=operationType.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("view")?"readonly":""%>> 
        </td>
        <%
        String sqlQuery=(String)iterFieldValues.next();
        %>

        <td width="35%" class="<%=classColor%>">
        <input type="text"  name="<%="sqlQuery"+i%>" value="<%=(sqlQuery!=null)?sqlQuery:""%>" size="65" MAXLENGTH="1000" <%=(!operationType.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("view"))&&fieldType.equalsIgnoreCase("codenosql")?"":"readonly"%>> 
        </td>
        <%
        String dateFormat=(String)iterFieldValues.next();
        %>
        <td width="5%" class="<%=classColor%>">
        <input type="text"  name="<%="dateFormat"+i%>" class="ibox" value="<%=(dateFormat!=null)?dateFormat:""%>" size="10" MAXLENGTH="1000" <%=(!operationType.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("view"))&&fieldType.equalsIgnoreCase("Date")?"":"readonly"%>> 
        </td>
        </tr>
        <%}%>
        <%
            }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            response.sendRedirect("error.jsp?entity=interfaces&mesg="+"Error while loading page." );
        }

        %>


        </table>
        <br>
        <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1">
        <tr>
        <input type="hidden" name="operationType" value="<%=operationType%>">
        <input type="hidden" name="changeType" value="">
        <%
            if(!operationType.trim().equals("view"))
            {
        %>
        <input name="addFileFormat" value="Submit" class="btn" type="button" onclick="this.form.changeType.value='addFileFormat';if(validate(this.form)) document.FileUploadFormatAdd.submit(); "></input>
        <%
            }
        %>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: For future reference, Sahil, your code would look better in StackOverflow if you *don't use* TABS and indent with spaces.

Comment: Such a correction can be made using the Pretty Diff tool, which does ignore white space inside ASP and PHP tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to set the max width/height and add scroll bars if the the table ends up being bigger?  If so, you can do this:

```
<div style="width:500px; height:500px overflow=auto">
<table>
<%buildTable()%>
</table>
</div>
```

`overflow=auto` will give you scroll bars if needed.  Check out [this](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_pos_overflow.asp) site for more details.  Hope this helps.